# React Router, won't push to new component - Cannot read property 'history' of undefined

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router

I've been having a serious headache and hopefully someone can help.

When logging out, I want to render the logged out home page, or a login page for users to be redirected to.

Instead, my navigation bar changes from logged in to logged out (so I know the user is logged out), but the login or home page component does not render.

I know the routes exist. `'/login' or '/'` ...I've tried both.

Here is the error.

```
user_navigation.jsx:20 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'history' of undefined
```

If I manually refresh my page it'll return to the homepage, but that is a redirect from the logged in component's componentDidMount function.

This also tells me that the `this.props.history.push('/login')` is not being reached in the promise because the user Id stays in the url unless I refresh and then it redirects to a page I am not sending it to.

Below is the logout function, and I'll add in the routes.

I appreciate any help in advance.

```
import React from 'react';
import { Nav, Navbar, NavItem, NavDropdown, MenuItem, Button } from 'react-bootstrap';
import UniversalButton from '../buttons/universal_button.jsx';
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import ReactLoading from 'react-loading';
import { clearAll } from '../../actions/reset_state';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { logout } from '../../actions/session_actions'

class UserNavigation extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.handleLogout = this.handleLogout.bind(this)
  }

  handleLogout(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.props.logout().then(() => {
      this.props.clearAll()
      this.props.history.push('/login')
    })
  }

  render() {
    return(
      <Navbar inverse collapseOnSelect className="nav-bar">
        <Navbar.Header>
          <Navbar.Brand>
            <a href="#">liftly</a>
          </Navbar.Brand>
          <Navbar.Toggle />
        </Navbar.Header>
        <Navbar.Collapse>
          <Nav>
            <NavItem eventKey={2} href="#">Leaderboard</NavItem>
            <NavDropdown eventKey={3} title="Portfolio" id="basic-nav-dropdown">
              <MenuItem eventKey={3.1}>Workout Log</MenuItem>
              <MenuItem eventKey={3.2}>Progress Tracker</MenuItem>
              <MenuItem eventKey={3.3}>Friends</MenuItem>
              <MenuItem divider />
              <MenuItem eventKey={3.3}>Coaching</MenuItem>
            </NavDropdown>
          </Nav>
          <Navbar.Form pullRight>
            <Button bsStyle="danger" onClick={this.handleLogout}>Log Out</Button>
          </Navbar.Form>
        </Navbar.Collapse>
      </Navbar>
    )
  }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
    clearAll: () => dispatch(clearAll()),
    logout: () => dispatch(logout())
  }
}
export default withRouter(connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(UserNavigation))
```

Routes

```
const app = () => (
  <div>
    <Navigation/>
    <Switch>
      <ProtectedRoute exact path='/' component={LoggedOutHomePage} />
      <AuthRoute path='/login' component={Login} />
      <AuthRoute path='/coach-signup' component={CoachSignup} />
      <AuthRoute path='/member-signup' component={MemberSignup} />
      <Route path ='/users/:userId' component={MembersHomePage} />
      <Route path ='/new-workout' component={NewWorkout} />
      <Route path ='/workout/:workoutId' component={WorkoutDetailsContainer} />
    </Switch>
  </div>
);

export default DragDropContext(HTML5Backend)(app);
```

Protected/Auth Routes

```
import React from 'react'
import { Route, withRouter, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';


const Protected = ({component: Component, path, loggedIn, currentUser}) => {
  return(
    <Route
      path={path}
      render={ props => loggedIn ? <Redirect to={`/users/${currentUser.id}`} />  : <Component {...props}/> }
    />
  )
}


const Auth = ({component: Component, path, loggedIn}) => {
  return(
    <Route
      path={path}
      render={ props => !loggedIn ? <Component {...props}/>  : <Redirect to="/" /> }
    />
  )
}


const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return{
    loggedIn: Boolean(state.session.currentUser),
    currentUser: state.session.currentUser
  }
}

export const ProtectedRoute = withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps)(Protected))
export const AuthRoute = withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps)(Auth))
```

Comment: is it because you misspelled `props` ? your code: `this.prop.history.push('/login')`

Comment: @azium I got excited for a second, but that didn't help. Now it keeps trying to push to the users home page and runs into an infinite loop because you can't access that page when logged out.

Comment: if you're logged out why would landing on login do anything but keep you there?

Comment: @azium my issues is when I am logged in, if I log out, I stay on the users home page with all of the information still showing. If I refresh the page, I am taken to the login page. I want the redirect to happen as soon as the logout button is pressed.

Comment: hmm sounds fishy. if `push('/login')` is working properly then you shouldn't be staying on the home page

Comment: Double check to make sure the record you are trying to access, actually exists.

Answer (score 0):

I finally fixed this by removing the promise.

Before:

```
handleLogout(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.props.logout().then(() => {
      this.props.clearAll()
      this.props.history.push('/login')
    })
  }
```

After:

```
  handleLogout(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.props.logout()
    this.props.clearCurUser()
    this.props.clearAll()
    this.props.history.push('/')
  }
```